# Using index in df name

Tags: r, for-loop, merge

I'm trying to merge 10 data frames on the intersection of two columns. I need it to return 25 data frames.

I have five portfolios of stocks ME_1, ME_2, ..., ME_5, and likewise 5 portfolios BM_1, BM_2, ..., BM_5.

R will not recognize BM_[i] as e.g. BM_1

```
for(i in 1:5) {
    for(j in 1:5) {
            pf <- paste("bm_", i, "me_", j, sep ="")
            assign(pf, merge(x=BM_[i], y=ME_[j], by = c("date", "tick")))

            pf <- pf %>%
                    arrange(tick, date) %>%
                    group_by(date_year.x) %>%
                    mutate(W = MVE_jun/sum(MVE_jun))
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in merge(x = BM_[i], y = ME_[j], by = c("date", "tick")) : 
  object 'BM_' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that there is no `BM_` dataset. We need `BM_1` `BM_2` instead of subsetting the columns using an object that was not there,  Using `paste` will get the character object names and then with `get`, we extract the value stored in that object

```
for(i in 1:5) {
   for(j in 1:5) {
        pf <- paste("bm_", i, "me_", j, sep ="")
        assign(pf, merge(x=get(paste0("BM_", i)),
               y=get(paste0("ME_", j)), by = c("date", "tick")))

        pf <- pf %>%
                arrange(tick, date) %>%
                group_by(date_year.x) %>%
                mutate(W = MVE_jun/sum(MVE_jun))
  }
}
```

NOTE: As noted in the comments `paste` is vectorized, so there is no need to call `paste` multipie times

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work for the first part and the correct merge is executed, but now the last part of the code won't work. I played around with it, and i cannot figure out if there's a problem to the way I am using pf in dplyr in the loop? i get the error Error in UseMethod("arrange_") : 
  no applicable method for 'arrange_' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: @claushojmark  YOu need to provide a small reproducible example and update it in your post for others to test